# Git override master with no history

Tags: git, github

We have several developers who work directly on the master branch. A few days ago there were some problems with our software.
After checking the source of the problem it led me to a specific file.
According to git history this file was not changed in the last 4 months. I'm absolutely sure I have committed a change to this file in the last 4 months.

Can there be a possible scenario that my commits were overridden without anyone being able to trace them with git history? How can I check if this scenario actually happened?

Comment: I think if they `git push --force` without merging your commit, it would overwrite history on the remote, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: You might be able to search the reflog to see if any older versions of `master` with your commit still exist. However, this is a very good reason for each developer to work on their own branches, if not their own clones of the entire repo, and merging into `master`.